# How is web data displayed in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, client-side

I previously read this from Mozilla's website and I have a question about how client-side code works.

> You might also hear the terms server-side and client-side code, specially in the context of web development. Client-side code is code that is run on the user's computer — when a web page is viewed, the page's client-side code is downloaded, then run and displayed by the browser. In this JavaScript module we are explicitly talking about client-side JavaScript.

When code is "downloaded" and run and displayed by the browser, where is it downloaded to? And is it temporary downloaded or stored on the users computer, or is it permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Files are downloaded and stored in cache and displayed. These files are html, css, JS, images etc. 
Server side are php etc these are not downloaded they are executed on server only

Answer (score 0):

All browsers have a directory somewhere on the local file system where they store downloaded scripts, stylesheets, images, etc. These are temporary and can be deleted by the user through corresponding functions of the browser, e.g. “[clear browsing data](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709?hl=en&visit_id=1-636284825398198428-3353983864&rd=1)” on Google Chrome.

[This page explains the location of the temporary files downloaded by Chrome on various systems](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/keN3Njx6gtM/4uJITn9Oa9oJ).

Comment: Thanks. Just to extend that a little bit, if you were to go to 'YouTube' and you watch a video. Is the video then temporarily downloaded too?

Comment: No, as far as I know, those videos are streamed, they don't leave temporary files on the local system

Comment: Not all browsers have a directory on the filesystem. For example, elinks does not have any cache. Also, modern browsers can be configured so that cache is disabled permanently. In addition, they usually don't cache (at least not on disk) in Incognito/Private Browsing mode.

Answer (score 0):

On the client, the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code as well as assets such as images and videos will be in some kind of memory, normally the main RAM. This memory is usually reclaimed as soon as you close the tab or the tab becomes inactive.

After decoding assets such as images, they may be copied to GPU memory, so that they can be rendered faster. 3D code may also be translated to graphic card instructions and reside temporarily on the graphics card.

If memory is tight, the operating system may swap it out to disk. Read up on [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) for more details.

Browsers do have a cache on disk. This is usually not used during first rendering (because then you'd have to wait on the disk before the page could be rendered), but speeds up future requests. As a programmer, you can set the HTTP [`Cache-Control`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) and [other headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching). It's up to the browser to decide when to delete cache files. Typically, they are deleted when they become stale, old, a limit of maximum cache size is reached, or the user deletes them by hand. It's up the browser and the user configuring it whether and how exactly caching is performed.

[Proxy servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) may also cache. Some large organizations use them to reduce and control Internet traffic. In this case, the code is downloaded once form the server to the proxy, and then from the proxy to each client.

An [HTML5 offline web applications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#offline) is usually stored on disk for a longer time. In contrast to a browser cache, an offline web application is not supposed to be deleted by a browser, but of course actual browser may behave differently. When a user enters a URL to an offline web application, it is loaded from disk before a request for a new version is sent. In contrast, with the normal browser cache, the resource is either present on disk (stale if the HTTP headers were incorrect) or it is downloaded.

[Service workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/) can also be installed by a website to intercept HTTP requests, much like offline web applications. They can store and load code/assets with [localStorage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-localstorage-attribute) on disk.

---

In summary, where code is stored depends on a lot of factors. By the nature of current computing architectures, the code will be in main memory at some time. Fortunately, your web application rarely has to care where the code actually is - the browser will make it available for you automatically. Nevertheless, by configuring caching headers and using offline web applications or service workers, you may achieve performance gains and ensure your website is available even when the Internet is not.

If you want to know what resources are cached in an actual website (at least in your setup), you can use the developer tools of your web browser (reachable with <kbd>F12</kbd> on many systems). For instance, here is this very page loaded with enabled cache on Chrome:

[image: Chrome developer tools: Network view]

Note the column *Size*, which says from which cache (Chrome has one in memory and one on disk) if any the file is coming.

Comment: Thank you, so let's say you have browser caching enabled. Does the browser cache all html, css, js, etc files? Or is it more selective and only caches some files over others? To give an example, let's say you're on FaceBook and each status post is dynamically loaded into the page. Are they downloaded into the RAM or cached, or both?

Comment: @Bail3y At first, everything is downloaded to the network card. From then, it is decrypted. With the current computing architecture, that's happening in RAM, but there's no reason why it could not happen directly on the CPU, at a dedicated encryption card, or a future network card (in theory).

Then, some resources are cached and others are not. That depends on the HTTP headers as well as browser configuration. Follow the links in this answer - for instance to the [HTTP `Cache-Control` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) for more technical details.